# Какую использовать библиотеку для метода LogitBoost?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

[image]

Не удается использовать алгоритм `LogitBoost`. Какую библиотеку использовать?

Comment: Попробуйте установить `skboost` с GitHub: `pip install git+https://github.com/hbldh/skboost`, но для этого, скорее всего, понадобиться компилятор `gcc`

Comment: пробовала skboost устанавливать, ничего хорошего. А есть иные пути для использования LogitBoost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не получается нормально установить `skboost` можно попробовать *грязный хак* - скачать [logitboost.py](https://github.com/hbldh/skboost/blob/master/skboost/logitboost.py) и скопировать этот файл в `<путь к Python>/lib/site-packages/logitboost.py`

Demo:

```
In [2]: from logitboost import LogitBoostClassifier

In [3]: LogitBoostClassifier?
Init signature:
LogitBoostClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', max_depth=1, max_features=None,
           max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
           min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
           min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
           presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best'), n_estimators=50, learning_rate=1.0, random_state=None)
Docstring:
An implementation of the LogitBoost classifier.

LogitBoost is an adaptive Newton algorithm for ﬁtting an
additive logistic regression model  by stagewise optimization of
the Bernoulli log-likelihood.
File:           c:\users\max\anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\logitboost.py
Type:           ABCMeta
```

Comment: ок, попробую сейчас

Comment: @user280357, ну как - получилось?

Comment: получилось) спасибо Вам

Comment: И GentleBoost тоже получилось, сделала по аналогии, спасииибо;)

Comment: Обязательно:))))